# How to use Bash to see what URL Firefox / Chrome is pulling?

Tags: macos, bash

If Firebug is not working or to grep the pulled URL, how do to it in Bash?

(on Windows, we can use Fiddler.  On Mac there seems to be a tool `tcpdump`)

Sometimes Firebug is not working or if to grep if a certain path or domain URL is being pull,
can that be done on the Mac's Bash?

(such as to check if there is a pull of connect.js, or anything from www.foobar.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

I don't know of a way to do it with bash, but from your question it sounds like the **[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)** packet sniffer would be a good option. You set it up to capture all packets matching a specific set of criteria (for instance, those going to host `www.example.com:80`) and you can then inspect the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X you may try http://www.charlesproxy.com (which is similar to Fiddler).